# update empty fields to Null but failed with NullIF or len(trim())=0

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I imported 4 flat flies into 4 sql tables. All the files has 77 columns. After import, I need to update empty fields to Null for all 4 tables. Below is the syntax:

```
DECLARE @iCount as integer
DECLARE @sCol1 as varchar(50)

--Replace all empty fields with NULL value

--Update audWeeklycs
Set @iCount =0
While @iCount<=76
Begin
  if @iCount <=9
  set @sCol1='[Col00'+CAST(@iCount as varchar (2))+']'
  else 
  set @sCol1='[Col0'+cast(@iCount as varchar (2))+']'

  Update MHP_Analysis.dbo.audWeeklycs
  Set @sCol1= case when len(rtrim(ltrim(@sCol1)))=0 then Null else @sCol1 end
  Set @iCount=@iCount+1
End
```

After run this statement, I found there is no change for empty fields. Can't figure out why. I also tried NULLIF function and didn't work.

Comment: What does "empty" mean? NULL, non-NULL empty string, something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your `UPDATE` statement can't update nothing in your database becaus it updates only variables. Let's see:

```
Update MHP_Analysis.dbo.audWeeklycs
Set @sCol1= case when len(rtrim(ltrim(@sCol1)))=0 then Null else @sCol1 end
```

Your algorythm which uses `WHILE` cycle is not the best solution, but in your case you can use dynamic SQL to make real update. Something like this:

```
-- somewhere outside your cycle
DECLARE @SqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)

-- replace your update statement with this code
SET @SqlCmd =
    'Update MHP_Analysis.dbo.audWeeklycs
    Set ' + @sCol1 + ' = case when len(rtrim(ltrim(' + @sCol1 + ')))=0 then Null else ' + @sCol1 +  ' end'
EXEC (@SqlCmd)
```